# Modify query to eliminate the need for a temp table

Tags: sql, select

The code below basically creates a table with two columns and twelve rows. 
While the final product is fine, I would like to eliminate the need to create a temporary table by replacing with an alias for the first select statement which i can then refer to it in the second select statement.

If you look at the code - the first select statement creates a table with one row and twelve columns. I then save the result as a tmptblTTM. I then pull data from this table into a second select query, transpose it, and then save it as a second table MX. I would like to directly refer to the results of the first select query in the second select query and skip the need for tmptblTTM altogether.

```
    DECLARE @queryDate1 datetime SET @queryDate1 = '03/31/2019';
    DECLARE @queryDate2 datetime set @queryDate2 = EOMONTH(@queryDate1,-1);
    DECLARE @queryDate3 datetime SET @queryDate3 = EOMONTH(@queryDate1,-2);
    DECLARE @queryDate4 datetime set @queryDate4 = EOMONTH(@queryDate1,-3);
    DECLARE @queryDate5 datetime SET @queryDate5 = EOMONTH(@queryDate1,-4);
    DECLARE @queryDate6 datetime set @queryDate6 = EOMONTH(@queryDate1,-5);
    DECLARE @queryDate7 datetime SET @queryDate7 = EOMONTH(@queryDate1,-6);
    DECLARE @queryDate8 datetime set @queryDate8 = EOMONTH(@queryDate1,-7);
    DECLARE @queryDate9 datetime SET @queryDate9 = EOMONTH(@queryDate1,-8);
    DECLARE @queryDate10 datetime set @queryDate10 = EOMONTH(@queryDate1,-9);
    DECLARE @queryDate11 datetime SET @queryDate11 = EOMONTH(@queryDate1,-10);
    DECLARE @queryDate12 datetime set @queryDate12 = EOMONTH(@queryDate1,-11);


    SELECT
         convert(varchar(10),@queryDate12,101) as [M1]
        ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate11,101) as [M2]
        ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate10,101) as [M3]
        ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate9,101) as [M4]
        ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate8,101) as [M5]
        ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate7,101) as [M6]
        ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate6,101) as [M7]
        ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate5,101) as [M8]
        ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate4,101) as [M9]
        ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate3,101) as [M10]
        ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate2,101) as [M11]
        ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate1,101) as [M12]



    INTO ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM

    CREATE TABLE tblMX (MX varchar (max), MDY date)

    INSERT INTO tblMX

    SELECT
        'M1' AS [MX], M1 AS date FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M2', M2 AS date FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M3', M3 AS [Date] FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M4', M4 AS [Date] FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M5', M5 AS [Date] FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M6', M6 AS [Date] FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M7', M7 AS [Date] FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M8', M8 AS [Date] FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M9', M9 AS [Date] FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M10', M10 AS [Date] FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M11', M11 AS [Date] FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M12', M12 AS [Date] FROM ga_financial.dbo.tmpTblTTM


select * from tblMX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE:

```
with tmpTblTTM as (
      <the code here>
 SELECT'M1' AS [MX], M1 AS date FROM tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M2', M2 AS date FROM tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M3', M3 AS [Date] FROM tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M4', M4 AS [Date] FROM tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M5', M5 AS [Date] FROM tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M6', M6 AS [Date] FROM tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M7', M7 AS [Date] FROM tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M8', M8 AS [Date] FROM tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M9', M9 AS [Date] FROM tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M10', M10 AS [Date] FROM tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M11', M11 AS [Date] FROM tmpTblTTM
        UNION ALL SELECT 'M12', M12 AS [Date] FROM tmpTblTTM;
```

That preserves your original query.  I prefer:

```
with tmpTblTTM as (
      . . .
     )
select v.*
from tmpTblTTM t cross apply
     (values ('M1', t.m1), ('M2', t.m2), . . .
     ) v(mx, date);
```

The `union`s are not necessary.

Comment: I like your idea on using a cross apply query. Can you tell me how I can save the results of the query into a temp table called MX?